# Evaluating "Table" expression with only sequential combination of parameter values

Tags: list-manipulation

I need to make a list by evaluating

```
{1, x, y, x*y}
```

on a sequence of points

```
{-10,10},{10,10},{10,-10},{-10, -10}
```

Neither

```
Table[{1, x, y, x*y}, {y, 10, -10, -20}, {x, -10, 10, 20}]
```

nor

```
Table[{1, x, y, x*y}, {y, {10, 10, -10, -10}}, {x, {-10, 10, 10, -10}}]
```

gave me the desired result.

I expect the result to be:

```
{{1, -10, 10, -100}, {1, 10, 10, 100}, {1, 10, -10, 100}, {1, -10, -10, -100}}
```

Is there a way to do it with `Table`? Thanks.

Comment: ricecakebear, thinking that it is a typo,  I changed `{-10,10}` in the last entry of your set of points to `{-10, -10}`.  If it is not a typo and it should stay `{-10,10}` please let me know, I will roll back my edit.

Comment: @kglr Yeah, it's a typo. Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[{x_, y_}] := {1, x, y, x*y}

f /@ {{-10, 10}, {10, 10}, {10, -10}, {-10, -10}}
```

> {{1, -10, 10, -100}, {1, 10, 10, 100}, {1, 10, -10, -100}, {1, -10, -10, -100}}

```
Table[f[i], {i, {{-10, 10}, {10, 10}, {10, -10}, {-10, -10}}}]
```

> {{1, -10, 10, -100}, {1, 10, 10, 100}, {1, 10, -10, -100}, {1, -10, -10, -100}}

Or

```
Table[{1, i[[1]], i[[2]], i[[1]] i[[2]]}, 
    {i, {{-10, 10}, {10, 10}, {10, -10}, {-10, -10}}}]
```

> {{1, -10, 10, -100}, {1, 10, 10, 100}, {1, 10, -10, -100}, {1, -10, -10, -100}}

Answer (score 1):

Some alternative solutions

```
points = {{-10, 10}, {10, 10}, {10, -10}, {-10, -10}};
```

Using `ComapApply` (new in 14.0)

```
f = {1 &, #1 &, #2 &, Times};

ComapApply[f] /@ points
```

{{1, -10, 10, -100}, {1, 10, 10, 100}, {1, 10, -10, -100}, {1, -10, -10, 100}}

Using `Comap` (also new in 14.0)

```
g = {1 &, First, Last, Apply @ Times};

Comap[g] /@ points
```

(* same result *)

Using `Query`

```
Query[All, g] @ points
```

(* same result *)

Answer (score 1):

Advertising for the resource function [TensorPureFunction](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/TensorPureFunction/):

```
f = ResourceFunction["TensorPureFunction"][#, {Variables[#]}] &@{1, x, y, x*y};

points = {{-10, 10}, {10, 10}, {10, -10}, {-10, -10}};

f /@ points
```

> {{1, -10, 10, -100}, {1, 10, 10, 100}, {1, 10, -10, -100}, {1, -10, -10, 100}}